# WPF DataGrid ContextMenu Command binding to MVVMLight RelayCommand<T> not always working

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light, wpfdatagrid

I have a WPF `DataGrid` for which I want to add a `ContextMenu` using MVVM. This `DataGrid` resides in a `UserControl` (I removed a bunch of stuff which I don't think have to do with the essence of the problem):

```
<UserControl x:Class="Legend.MarkerMultiStatisticsControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:legend="clr-namespace:Legend"
             Name="Self"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <GroupBox Header="{Binding ElementName=Self, Path=StaisticsData.Title}">
        <DockPanel>
            <DataGrid 
                      DataContext="{Binding ElementName=Self}"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=Self, Path=StaisticsData.Statistics}"
                      SelectionMode="Single"
                      CurrentCell="{Binding ElementName=Self, Path=CurrentCell, Mode=OneWayToSource}">
                <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=PlacementTarget.DataContext}"
                                 ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Commands}">
                        <ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                                <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Header}"></Setter>
                                <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Command, diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}"></Setter>
                                <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGrid}, Path=DataContext.CurrentLegendCell}"></Setter>
                            </Style>
                        </ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
                    </ContextMenu>
                </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
            </DataGrid>
        </DockPanel>
    </GroupBox>
</UserControl>
```

This control has a `DependencyProperty` called `Command` to which I bind the menu's `ItemsSource` and its type is `ObservableCollection<LegendCommand>` with `LegendCommand` being

```
public class LegendCommand : ObservableObject
{
    private string _header;
    private ICommand _command;

    public string Header
    {
        get { return _header; }
        set { Set(()=>Header, ref _header, value); }
    }

    public ICommand Command
    {
        get { return _command; }
        set { Set(() => Command, ref _command, value); }
    }
}
```

These commands are generated in different places in my view models.

In one place (inside an `Adapter` class whose `Commands` are bound to the control's `Commands`) I have the following:

```
Commands.Add(new LegendCommand
            {
                Header = "From inside adapter...",
                Command = new RelayCommand<LegendCellInfo>(info =>
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("State: {0}, Property: {1}", info.State, info.PropertyName));
                })
            });
```

And in a different place (the view model which holds the `Adapter`) I have the following:

```
adapter.Commands.Add(new LegendCommand
            {
                Header = "Select",
                Command = new RelayCommand<LegendCellInfo>(info =>
                {
                    // selection logic
                })
            });
```

My problem is that the "From inside adapter..." command is executed but "Select" isn't. I put a breakpoint in the "Select" code but it's never called.

The binding of the `ContextMenu`'s `ItemsSource` to the `Commands` property works as I see both options in the menu.
The binding of the `ICommans`'s probably works because one of the commands is executed.

I debugged the code and binding and have the following info:

The `Commands` collection holds two elements whose hash codes are 40262542 and 26818564 (got them from running `adapter.Commands[0].Command.GetHashCode()` and `adapter.Commands[1].Command.GetHashCode()` in Visual Studio's Immediate Window).

The binding tracing gives the following output when I right-click the `DataGrid`:

```
System.Windows.Data Warning: 56 : Created BindingExpression (hash=11440639) for Binding (hash=54536677)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 58 :   Path: 'Command'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 60 : BindingExpression (hash=11440639): Default mode resolved to OneWay
System.Windows.Data Warning: 61 : BindingExpression (hash=11440639): Default update trigger resolved to PropertyChanged
System.Windows.Data Warning: 62 : BindingExpression (hash=11440639): Attach to System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem.Command (hash=54276594)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 67 : BindingExpression (hash=11440639): Resolving source 
System.Windows.Data Warning: 70 : BindingExpression (hash=11440639): Found data context element: MenuItem (hash=54276594) (OK)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 78 : BindingExpression (hash=11440639): Activate with root item LegendCommand (hash=5940773)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 108 : BindingExpression (hash=11440639):   At level 0 - for LegendCommand.Command found accessor RuntimePropertyInfo(Command)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 104 : BindingExpression (hash=11440639): Replace item at level 0 with LegendCommand (hash=5940773), using accessor RuntimePropertyInfo(Command)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 101 : BindingExpression (hash=11440639): GetValue at level 0 from LegendCommand (hash=5940773) using RuntimePropertyInfo(Command): RelayCommand`1 (hash=40262542)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 80 : BindingExpression (hash=11440639): TransferValue - got raw value RelayCommand`1 (hash=40262542)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 89 : BindingExpression (hash=11440639): TransferValue - using final value RelayCommand`1 (hash=40262542)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 56 : Created BindingExpression (hash=31617173) for Binding (hash=54536677)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 58 :   Path: 'Command'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 60 : BindingExpression (hash=31617173): Default mode resolved to OneWay
System.Windows.Data Warning: 61 : BindingExpression (hash=31617173): Default update trigger resolved to PropertyChanged
System.Windows.Data Warning: 62 : BindingExpression (hash=31617173): Attach to System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem.Command (hash=16119107)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 67 : BindingExpression (hash=31617173): Resolving source 
System.Windows.Data Warning: 70 : BindingExpression (hash=31617173): Found data context element: MenuItem (hash=16119107) (OK)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 78 : BindingExpression (hash=31617173): Activate with root item LegendCommand (hash=16131920)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 107 : BindingExpression (hash=31617173):   At level 0 using cached accessor for LegendCommand.Command: RuntimePropertyInfo(Command)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 104 : BindingExpression (hash=31617173): Replace item at level 0 with LegendCommand (hash=16131920), using accessor RuntimePropertyInfo(Command)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 101 : BindingExpression (hash=31617173): GetValue at level 0 from LegendCommand (hash=16131920) using RuntimePropertyInfo(Command): RelayCommand`1 (hash=26818564)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 80 : BindingExpression (hash=31617173): TransferValue - got raw value RelayCommand`1 (hash=26818564)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 89 : BindingExpression (hash=31617173): TransferValue - using final value RelayCommand`1 (hash=26818564)
```

If I understand correctly, we can see that two binding operations take place - the first results in binding to `'RelayCommand'1 (hash=40262542)` and the second to `'RelayCommand'1 (hash=26818564)` - incidentally these are the hash codes for my two commands.

Also, no exceptions or other errors occur.

I'm stuck in my investigation. Where else to look?

**UPDATE 1**:
When I change the code in "Select" command to the following instead of the code I had before:

```
adapter.Commands.Add(new LegendCommand
            {
                Header = "Select",
                Command = new RelayCommand<LegendCellInfo>(info =>
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("yes");
                })
            });
```

then the code starts working all of a sudden...

**UPDATE 2**:
The original command uses members of the `Adapter` class. Searching online for problems with MVVMLight `RelayCommand` and member functions found this SO question: [RelayCommand with Argument throwing MethodAccessException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19468086/relaycommand-with-argument-throwing-methodaccessexception)
(but obviously I want to continue using MVVMLight...)

**UPDATE 3**: Read the MVVMLight code for `RelayCommand` and it doesn't save a hard reference to the method so I think that nothing is keeping the lambda alive. Will refactor the code now and update here if it works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Indeed the reason is that the "Select" command was not kept alive by MVVMLight's weak reference.
I wrote about it in more detail here: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/dinazil/2015/01/16/relaycommands-weakfuncs/

Comment: Works like a magic. In other words, the solution is to store the Action<T> to a property before assign it to RelayCommand ctor

Comment: @Ryan So happy this helped someone :-)

Comment: Link is broken!